# Clean way to set numerical value by comparison conditional

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I have the following const "maxRange" ... that compares two values and then sets to one of those values if less than. Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this same logic?

```
const maxRange = Math.round(averageTotalPrice / 50) * 50 * 5.5 < maxTotalPrice ? Math.round(averageTotalPrice / 50) * 50 * 5.5 : maxTotalPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `Math.min`:

```
const maxRange = Math.min(
    Math.round(averageTotalPrice / 50) * 50 * 5.5,
    maxTotalPrice
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this better

```
let round = Math.round(averageTotalPrice / 50) * 50 * 5.5;
const maxRange = Math.min(round, maxTotalPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting rid of the [magical numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `50` and `5.5` and using `Math.min` instead of the ternary operator.

If `Math.round(averageTotalPrice / MAGICAL_50) * MAGICAL_50 * MAGICAL_5_5` is not absolutely obvious in the domain you are working on, I would also put that in a constant just to make clear what that is all about.

Here is a hypothetical:

```
const BUCKET_SIZE = 5.5;
const WHOLESALE_AMOUNT = 50;
const maxRange = Math.min(Math.round(averageTotalPrice / WHOLESALE_AMOUNT ) * WHOLESALE_AMOUNT * BUCKET_SIZE, maxTotalPrice);
```